# With Beautiful Soup get specific string in <div> tag

Tags: python, dictionary, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a list of  tags that I extracted with:

```
soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'formelement'}):
```

Output is:

```
[<div class="formelement">
 <label class="libelle" for="field_tit">Etat :</label>
                    Publié              </div>,
 <div class="formelement">
 <label class="libelle" for="field_tit">Type de produit :</label>
                    Plaque de plâtre                </div>,
 <div class="formelement">
 <label class="libelle" for="field_tit">Numéro :</label>
                                            PP/48-05                                    </div>,
 <div class="formelement">
 <label class="libelle" for="field_tit">Titulaire :</label>
                    CIA ESPAÑOLA DE AISLAMIENTOS SA             </div>,
 <div class="formelement">
 <label class="libelle" for="field_ref">Usine :</label>
                    39              </div>,
 <div class="formelement">
 <label class="libelle" for="field_tit">Date d'admission :</label>
                        13/07/2017                      </div>,
 <div class="formelement">
 <label class="libelle" for="field_tit">Date de reconduction :</label>
                        04/02/2021                      </div>,
 <div class="formelement">
 <label class="libelle" for="field_tit">Date de fin de validité :</label>
                        04/05/2022                      </div>,
 <div class="formelement">
 <label class="libelle" for="field_tit">Certificat PDF :</label>
 <a href="application/docs/certificats/PP_48_05.pdf" target="_blank">
 <img src="public/images/pdf.gif" title="Télécharger le certificat au format PDF"/>
 </a>
 </div>]
```

My goal is to have a dict with :

```
product_data = {
"Numéro": "PP/48-05",
"Titulaire": "CIA ESPAÑOLA DE AISLAMIENTOS SA",
"Usine": "39",
"Date de fin de validité": "04/05/2022",
"Certificat PDF": "application/docs/certificats/PP_48_05.pdf"
}
```

I tried with

```
for div in soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'formelement'}):
        product_data[div.text] = div.next_sibling
```

but it will take all strings inside the  tag (obviously) and don't find any way to get the two string inside the div separately. How can I get theses strings separately?

I hope that my question is enough explicit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can destroy/decompose the inner tag

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html="""
<div class="formelement">
 <label class="libelle" for="field_tit">Etat :</label>
                    Publié              </div>,
 <div class="formelement">
 <label class="libelle" for="field_tit">Type de produit :</label>
                    Plaque de plâtre                </div>,
 <div class="formelement">
 <label class="libelle" for="field_tit">Numéro :</label>
                                            PP/48-05                                    </div>,
 <div class="formelement">
 <label class="libelle" for="field_tit">Titulaire :</label>
                    CIA ESPAÑOLA DE AISLAMIENTOS SA             </div>,
 <div class="formelement">
 <label class="libelle" for="field_ref">Usine :</label>
                    39              </div>,
 <div class="formelement">
 <label class="libelle" for="field_tit">Date d'admission :</label>
                        13/07/2017                      </div>,
 <div class="formelement">
 <label class="libelle" for="field_tit">Date de reconduction :</label>
                        04/02/2021                      </div>,
 <div class="formelement">
 <label class="libelle" for="field_tit">Date de fin de validité :</label>
                        04/05/2022                      </div>,
 <div class="formelement">
 <label class="libelle" for="field_tit">Certificat PDF :</label>
 <a href="application/docs/certificats/PP_48_05.pdf" target="_blank">
 <img src="public/images/pdf.gif" title="Télécharger le certificat au format PDF"/>
 </a>
 </div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
data = {}
for div in soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'formelement'}):
    label = div.find('label')
    key = label.text[:-2]
    label.decompose()
    try:
        value = div.find('a').get('href')
    except AttributeError:
        value = div.text.strip()
    data[key] = value
print(data)
```

output

```
{'Etat': 'Publié', 'Type de produit': 'Plaque de plâtre',
 'Numéro': 'PP/48-05', 'Titulaire': 'CIA ESPAÑOLA DE AISLAMIENTOS SA', 
 'Usine': '39', "Date d'admission": '13/07/2017', 
 'Date de reconduction': '04/02/2021', 'Date de fin de validité': '04/05/2022', 
 'Certificat PDF': 'application/docs/certificats/PP_48_05.pdf'}
```

Comment: Thank you! It is exactly what I want, I didn't know the decompose() function.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """
<div class="formelement">
 <label class="libelle" for="field_tit">Etat :</label>
                    Publié              </div>,
 <div class="formelement">
 <label class="libelle" for="field_tit">Type de produit :</label>
                    Plaque de plâtre                </div>,
 <div class="formelement">
 <label class="libelle" for="field_tit">Numéro :</label>
                                            PP/48-05                                    </div>,
 <div class="formelement">
 <label class="libelle" for="field_tit">Titulaire :</label>
                    CIA ESPAÑOLA DE AISLAMIENTOS SA             </div>,
 <div class="formelement">
 <label class="libelle" for="field_ref">Usine :</label>
                    39              </div>,
 <div class="formelement">
 <label class="libelle" for="field_tit">Date d'admission :</label>
                        13/07/2017                      </div>,
 <div class="formelement">
 <label class="libelle" for="field_tit">Date de reconduction :</label>
                        04/02/2021                      </div>,
 <div class="formelement">
 <label class="libelle" for="field_tit">Date de fin de validité :</label>
                        04/05/2022                      </div>,
 <div class="formelement">
 <label class="libelle" for="field_tit">Certificat PDF :</label>
 <a href="application/docs/certificats/PP_48_05.pdf" target="_blank">
 <img src="public/images/pdf.gif" title="Télécharger le certificat au format PDF"/>
 </a>
 </div>
 """

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")

allowed_keys = {
    "Numéro",
    "Titulaire",
    "Usine",
    "Date de fin de validité",
    "Certificat PDF",
}

data = []
for f in soup.select(".formelement"):
    key_value = f.get_text(strip=True, separator="|").split("|")
    if len(key_value) == 1:
        a = f.find("a")
        if a:
            key_value = [key_value[0], a["href"]]
        else:
            continue
    key_value[0] = key_value[0].strip(" :")
    if key_value[0] not in allowed_keys:
        continue
    data.append(key_value)


out = dict(data)
print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
{
    "Numéro": "PP/48-05",
    "Titulaire": "CIA ESPAÑOLA DE AISLAMIENTOS SA",
    "Usine": "39",
    "Date de fin de validité": "04/05/2022",
    "Certificat PDF": "application/docs/certificats/PP_48_05.pdf",
}
```